# show same month/week/day upon refresh of fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using a fullcalendar plugin to display various events.

My problem is when I change the month/week being viewed, then refresh, I get taken back to the current month/week, when I want to stay on the same month/week I was viewing beforehand. i.e. If it's August right now, and I go back to July, then refresh, I want the page to display the calendar for July and not August.

Code that gives a working calendar for the problem specified is given below. Note that I understand this calendar doesn't fully work (can't add events etc.), but it saving it as index.html and opening it will show the problem I have of not opening at the previous view after a refresh.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Jquery Fullcalandar Integration with PHP and Mysql</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    allDaySlot: false,
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: [{"id":1,"title":"one","start":"2019-08-11 00:00:00","end":"2019-08-12 00:00:00", 'color': 'Fuchsia'}],
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
     var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
     if(title)
     {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Added Successfully");
       }
      })
     }
    },
    editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert('Event Update');
      }
     })
    },

    eventDrop:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function()
      {
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert("Event Updated");
      }
     });
    },

    eventClick:function(event)
    {
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
     {
      var id = event.id;
      $.ajax({
       url:"delete.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{id:id},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Event Removed");
       }
      })
     }
    },

   });
  });
   
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <h2 align="center"><a href="#">Jquery Fullcalandar Integration with PHP and Mysql</a></h2>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I wish to add a property somewhere (presumably after line 14 `var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({` ) that makes it so after a refresh, I end up on the month/week I was previously on.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to refresh the page at all?  Do you just mean when you come back to it another day? But if you want to do this, you could store the current date in localstorage after every viewRender, and retrieve it before first loading the calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this code to solve your problem

```
$(document).on('click', '.fc-next-button,.fc-prev-button', function () {
 localStorage.setItem('savedMonth',$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').intervalStart._d);
});
if(localStorage.getItem('savedMonth')!=null){
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',localStorage.getItem('savedMonth'));
}
```

or you can do this using cookies instead of local storage